# Average of rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below table

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4   Col5
TotalAvg 68.79 65.39 88.21  63.14
```

I am already saving the total of all columns in the TotalAvg row but now I want to calculate the Average of the TotalAvg row. Can someone please tell me how I can calculate row average.

I am looking for

```
Select Avg(Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5)
    where Col1 = 'TotalAvg'
```

Thanks

Comment: `select (Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5)/4` ?

Comment: Any null values in the table?

Comment: That's exactly what I was gonna say..there might be null values so average might have taken care of that.

Comment: Just change your commas into plus signs, and wrap each column with ISNULL to handle NULLs.

Comment: @SeanLange - Well, you also need to account for that in the denominator *(`1,2,3,NULL` => `(1+2+3)/3`)*

Comment: @MatBailie I suppose you are right. But this question is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

If by chance you need a more dynamic approach (i.e. variable columns), and IF you're open to a TVF, consider the following:

> **EDIT**

The 1st parameter is a delimited list of columns to exclude.  For example: `'IDNr,Year,AnyOtherNumericCol'`.

**Example**

```
Select A.* 
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Stat-Row-Agg]('',(Select A.* for XML Raw)) B
```

**Returns**

```
Col1        Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    RetCnt  RetSum  RetMin  RetMax  RetAvg  RetStd
TotalAvg    68.79   65.39   88.21   63.14   4       285.53  63.14   88.21   71.3825 11.4562162892757
```

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Stat-Row-Agg](@Exclude varchar(500),@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetCnt = Count(Value)
          ,RetSum = Sum(Value)
          ,RetMin = Min(Value)
          ,RetMax = Max(Value)
          ,RetAvg = Avg(Value)
          ,RetStd = Stdev(Value)
    From  (
            Select Item  = convert(varchar(100),xAttr.query('local-name(.)'))
                  ,Value = try_convert(float,xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)'))
             From  @XML.nodes('//@*') x(xAttr)
          ) S
    Where charindex(','+S.Item+',',','+@Exclude+',')=0
);
```

> **EDIT 2**

If the columns are fixed, and performance is paramount, then...

```
Select A.* 
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select AvgVal = avg(Value)
                 From (values (Col2)
                             ,(Col3)
                             ,(Col4)
                             ,(Col5)
                      ) B1(Value)
             ) B
```

Comment: Thank you so much John for helping out.

Comment: @user1221989 Happy to help.  Failed to mention the first parameter is a comma delimited list of columns to exclude  i.e.  'SomeNumericCol,AnotherNumericCol'

Comment: @user1221989 See EDIT and EDIT 2

Answer (score 0):

If some of them may have NULL values, you could still use `AVG()` inside an `APPLY`.

```
SELECT
  yourTable.Col1,
  RowStats.avg
FROM
  yourTable
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    AVG(x) AS avg
  FROM
  (
    SELECT yourTable.col2   AS x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yourTable.col3   AS x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yourTable.col4   AS x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yourTable.col5   AS x
  )
    pivot
)
  AS rowStats
```